# Even after popping the element, iterator is still showing that in vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have pushed 1 element in vector and popped it in this program:

```
 `
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> ivec;
ivec.push_back(9);
vector<int>::iterator l=ivec.end();
cout<<"Size before popping = "<<ivec.size()<<"|| last element before deletion is = "<<*--l<<endl<<endl;
ivec.pop_back();
cout<<"size after popping = "<<ivec.size()<<"|| after deletion, last element is = "<<*l<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Even after popping the element, iterator is outputting 9. Why is it still pointing to the deleted value? Doesn't this behavior make iterators untrustworthy?

Is it because the iterator might be pointing to the memory which was previously the part of the vector? Shouldn't the iterator sync it with the changed size?

> g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)

Comment: *Doesn't this behavior make iterators untrustworthy?* No it doesn't.  By modifying the vector you invalidate the iterator.  It is your responsibility to watch for that.

Comment: You are invoking Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Because you have a bug in your code, and some bugs in C++ lead to strange observed behaviour.

Comment: @NathanOliver "invalidated"?? You mean now the iterator becomes useless after modification?

Comment: @infinite see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: @infinite the **iterator** is invalidated, but the **memory** it was pointing at may still be allocated. Popping an element does not reallocate the vector's capacity, but it may shift remaining data around.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.